# Stop calendar from asking me if I want to turn on notifications

Tags: samsung

Every time I put a new event in my calendar that came with the phone it asks if I want to turn on notifications in order to get reminders for the event.  How do I shut this off?  I have already turned off notifications for the app.  I never want a reminder.  Also, is there any way to switch the color order around for color coding events so it automatically selects purple instead of ugly teal as the default?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer and am posting it here for anyone that's having the same issue. Open the calendar app, go to three dots at the top, select settings, go to set default reminders, set both to none. That should stop the anniying pop up.  I am still looking for a way to rearrange color order.  Apparently they will let you do it with stickers but not with colors.